# how do i set orfox to id its IP in a specific country?

Tags: orbot

i need to access a country specific website.
i am outside the secific country using  orbot and orfox on an android 1 device.
Can a community member pls advise on a potential  relay or bridge  process that i must follow to allow me access to the site  using orbot/orfox from outside the websites country of origin?
would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This would be using *Orbot* not *Orfox*, Orfox is the browser and Orbot provides the Tor client and allows configuration of it.

Open Orbot, swipe in from the left of the screen. This should give you a pull out menu.

It should have "Apps VPN Mode" "Bridges" and below that a pulldown list, by default set as "World (Location)". Use the pulldown list to select your desired location to Exit from.

That should be all you need to do but you might want to Stop and Start Orbot just to be sure (I find sometimes it needs this to change bridge configuration).